# How to do a case is INSENSITIVE check using IS DISTINCT FROM

Tags: postgresql

I have to compare the values of multiple columns which includes character, integer, and date types columns from 2 tables.

I have used the following type of SQL ( actual SQL have 100+ column each side of DISTINCT FROM ).

```
SELECT table1.* from
Table1 JOIN table2 ON ( table1.id = table2.id )
WHERE
   ( table1.name, table1.email, table1.dob, table1.application_id )
 IS DISTINCT FROM 
  ( table2.name, table2.email, table2.dob, table2.application_id );
```

if email id/name has case difference then it is considering them distinct.

using LOWER() can solve the problem but that I need to write for each text column. Can I do this in any other way?

Comment: If you really have a long term need to treat your data in a case insensitive way, then consider storing it as all lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: Unfortunately using `lower()` or `upper()` is the only option :(